# PHP pagination function

Tags: php, pagination

```
public function paging($limit,$numRows,$page){

    $allPages       = ceil($numRows / $limit);

    $start          = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $querystring = "";

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "page") $paginHTML .= "$key=$value&amp;";
    }

    $paginHTML = "";

    $paginHTML .= "Pages: ";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $allPages; $i++) {
        $paginHTML .= "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"selected\" " : "");
        $paginHTML .= "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$i";
        $paginHTML .= "\">$i</a> ";
    }

    return $paginHTML;

 }
```

This is my pagination function for MVC pattern implementation.But this function has not displayed next and prev links.

I need to return HTML variable for pagination with previous and next link to controller.

I passed these variable to this function from controller.

```
$limit,$numRows,$page
```

How can I get next and prev links to above function.

Comment: Not about this topic but you should adjust the code as `$start = ($page-1)*$limit+1;`

Answer (score 0):

I have added some conditions in the loop itself.

Hope they work.

Try the following:

```
<?php
public function paging($limit,$numRows,$page){

    $allPages       = ceil($numRows / $limit);

    $start          = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $querystring = "";

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "page") $paginHTML .= "$key=$value&amp;";
    }

    $paginHTML = "";

    $paginHTML .= "Pages: ";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $allPages; $i++) {
        if ($i>1) {
                    $prev = $i-1;
                    $paginHTML .= '<a href="?'.$querystring.'page='.$prev'">Previous</a>';
                }
                $paginHTML .= "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"selected\" " : "");
        $paginHTML .= "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$i";
        $paginHTML .= "\">$i</a> ";
                if ($i<$allPages) {
                    $next = $i+1;
                    $paginHTML .= '<a href="?'.$querystring.'page='.$next'">Next</a>';
                }
    }

    return $paginHTML;

 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this pagination class like bellow inside my controller
    case '' :

```
    $page = isset ( $_REQUEST ['page'] ) ? $_REQUEST ['page'] : 1;

    $limit          = 5;

    $allStudent     = $student->getAllStudents();

    $numRows        = count($allStudent);

    $start          = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $students       = $student->getStudentsWithLimit($start,$limit);

    $paginHTML      = $pagin->paging($limit,$numRows,$page);


    $view->render('view/allStudent.php', array('allStudent' => $students,'pagin' => $paginHTML ));

    break;
```

Get record function in Model class

```
public function getStudentsWithLimit($start,$limit){

    $stmt       = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM student LIMIT $start, $limit");
    $results    = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $results;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should page with next and previous links with a max of 5 on either side of current page.

Pass in a function if you want the link formatted differently.

I've only given this very limited testing, and its been pulled out of a class, so you could replace some hard coded values in here with parameters of references to $this

```
     function get_paging_links($result_count, callable $format_function=null)
     {
         if(!$format_function){
             $format_function = function($url,$page,$qs){
                 $qs['page'] = $page;
                 return $url.'?'.http_build_query($qs);
             };
         }

        $per_page = 5;
        $total_pages = ceil($result_count / $per_page);
        $return = [];


        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$qs);

        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        //Remove existing query_string.
        if($pos = strpos($url,'?')){
            $url = substr($url,0,$pos);
        }

        $current_page = isset($qs['page']) ? $qs['page'] : 1;

        $previous = $current_page -1;

        if ($previous) {
            $return['previous'] = $format_function($url,$previous,$qs);
        }

        for($i = max(1,$current_page-5); $i <= min($total_pages,$current_page+5); $i++) {
            $return["$i"] = $format_function($url,$i,$qs);
        }

        $next_page = $current_page + 1;

        if ($next_page < $total_pages){
            $return['next'] = $format_function($url,$next_page,$qs);
        }

        return $return;
     }
```